# How to push a option from HTML to an array of an object in JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I have waiter Objects witch each have their own array.

I have all the options populated in JS

In HTML the two select elements are populated with:
i) waiter Objects
ii) foodItem Objects

I have a button which on submit I want to push the foodItem to the selected waiters array.

I can maunally push the foodSelection to the waiterSelection

waiters[0].order.push('Penne Primvera');

But I am not sure how this works with forms.

```
<HTML>
        <form id="mainForm">
            <select id="menuMain" name="foodOrder"><option>Mains</option></select>
            <select id="waiters" name="waiterSelection"><option>Waiters</option></select>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">         
        </form>

<JS>
//////////

//Waiter Objects

///////////

//Waiter constructor
function Waiter (name, order) {
    this.name = name;
    this.order = [];
}

//Waiter objects
var waiterOne = new Waiter('Timo');
var waiterTwo = new Waiter('Lucian');
var waiterThree = new Waiter('Arpi');




//Array to store waiters
var waiters = [
    waiterOne,
    waiterTwo,
    waiterThree
];


var waiter = document.getElementById('waiters');
var count = waiters.length;

//Adds the number of waiters to the options menu in the HTML file
for(var i = 0; i< count; i++){
    var waiterSelection = waiters[i];
    var selectedWaiter = waiterSelection.name;
    waiter.options.add(new Option(selectedWaiter));   
};




//////////////

//Food Items

////////////

//Food Constructor 
function Item (item, price) {
    this.item = item;
    this.price = price;
}

//Food objects
var iOne = new Item('Peene Primviera', 14.60);
var iTwo = new Item('Lasagne', 14.50);
var iThree = new Item('Fillet Steak', 20.00);

//Array for foodSlection
var maindItemList = [
    iOne,
    iTwo,
    iThree
];

//Add the Options to the DropDownList Mains.
var foodSelection = document.getElementById('menuMain')
var count = maindItemList.length;
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var itemSelection = maindItemList[i];
    var value = itemSelection.item   + " (" + itemSelection.price +")"
    foodSelection.options.add(new Option(value));
};

////////////

//Form Submit

///////////

var form = document.getElementById('mainForm');
form.onSubmit = function (e) {
    console.log(form.foodSelection.value)
};
```

The result should be that when the form is submitted, the selected waiter should have the selected food pushed to their order Array.

```
Waiter {name: "Timo", order: Array(1)}
name: "Timo"
order: ["Penne Primvera"]
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go! I made some slight improvements too.

- prefer `const` over `let`
- keep things simple
- Use `Array` methods when applicable
- Use object destructuring

```js
//Waiter constructor
function Waiter(name, order) {
  this.name = name;
  this.order = [];
}

//Array to store waiters
const waiters = [new Waiter("Timo"), new Waiter("Lucian"), new Waiter("Arpi")];

const waiterEl = document.getElementById("waiters");

//Adds the number of waiters to the options menu in the HTML file
waiters.forEach(({ name }) => waiterEl.options.add(new Option(name)));

//Food Constructor
function Item(item, price) {
  this.item = item;
  this.price = price;
  this.label = `${item} (${price})`;
}

//Array for foodSlection
const foods = [
  new Item("Peene Primviera", 14.6),
  new Item("Lasagne", 14.5),
  new Item("Fillet Steak", 20.0)
];

//Add the Options to the DropDownList Mains.
const foodEl = document.getElementById("menuMain");

foods.forEach(({ label, item }) => foodEl.options.add(new Option(label, item)));

const formEl = document.getElementById("mainForm");

formEl.onsubmit = function(e) {
  const foodItem = foodEl.options[foodEl.selectedIndex].value;
  const waiterName = waiterEl.options[waiterEl.selectedIndex].value;
  const waiter = waiters.find(({ name }) => name === waiterName);

  if (waiter && foodItem) {
    waiter.order.push(foodItem);
    console.log(waiters);
  }
  return false; // prevents redirect/refresh
};
```

```html
<form id="mainForm" action="#">
    <select id="menuMain" name="foodOrder"><option>Mains</option></select>
    <select id="waiters" name="waiterSelection"><option>Waiters</option></select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">         
</form>
```

**Update**

If you want to persist your `waiters` you can do so with localStorage or cookies. It won't work if I add it to the snippet in my answer because it's a sandboxed environment where you can't access localStorage or cookies due to security reasons.

But you would do something along these lines (not tested):

- add this to the last line in `onsubmit`

```js
    document.cookie=`waiters=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(waiters))}` // commas are not allowed in cookies and encodeURIComponent replaces commas with the escape sequence %2C
```

- change the line where `waiters` is defined to

```js
   const cookieValue =
      document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)waiters\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/,
      "$1");

   const waiters = cookieValue ?
     JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(cookieValue)) :
     [new Waiter("Timo"), new Waiter("Lucian"), new Waiter("Arpi")];
```

Comment: Thank you this is an amazing way to learn I rely appreciate it, I was wondering is there away of storing the information so after refresh the orders stay inside the array? Is this even possible with JS alone?

Comment: You're welcome! Yes it's doable with JS alone, I'll update my answer.

Comment: The updated code did not work for me im going to do some research myself about JSON and parsing , when I hit the submit button it seems to reload the page maybe ill leave this journey for another day. Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: Did you remove `return false;` from `onsubmit`? Here's a working example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/a-morn/pen/KORyyO)

Comment: No I did not but thanks again for all the constructive help :)